# Debug bundle.js file in browser without modifying webpack config

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, webpack, bundle

Let's say I want to inspect and debug the js source code using the browser devtools. When I view the site's js sources there is only the bundled.js file, which is difficult to debug.

Without having access to the site's webpack config I cannot specify the flag `devtool: "source-map"`, which gives better visibility into what is happening.

Are there any other options for debugging the bundle.js code or getting access to a source map?

Comment: Have you seen this https://reactjs.org/community/debugging-tools.html ?

Comment: @Morta1 Yea that helps a little bit but it is still very limited to functions attached to the html elements. Doesn't even provide visibility into lifecycle methods.